# Need explanation on BUCKET and rand() function in Hive

Tags: hive

Can anyone please explain me what the following queries mean?

```
1. SELECT * from numbers TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 3 OUT OF 10 ON rand()) s;
2. SELECT * from numbers TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 3 OUT OF 10 ON number) s;
3. SELECT * from numbers TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 2 ON number) s;
4. SELECT * from numbers TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 2 OUT OF 2 ON number) s;
```

I tried to understand the above queries in all possible ways I could, but couldn't move a bit forward. Please explain me in detail.

Thanks in advance.

[Source](http://www.gocit.vn/files/Oreilly.Programming.Hive-www.gocit.vn.pdf) 
Page Number - 110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John Deer, When we bucket on a column, the data is divided into the specified buckets and accordingly the files are created in Hadoop. While retrieving data a specified bucket, the data is pulled out from the specified bucket/file. So, the data remains unchanged.

Whereas, if we use rand function(which produces random numbers), the data is changed with every execution of rand().

1. SELECT * from numbers TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 3 OUT OF 10 ON rand()) s;

Explanation: Here, there are 10 buckets wherein the data is cased. We are using rand function on the bucketed column to retrieve the data. So, instead of from the 3rd bucket, it pulls random data. So the data is changed with every execution of rand.

3. SELECT * from numbers TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 2 ON number) s;

Explanation: Here, there are 2 buckets wherein the data is cased. We are using the bucketed column to retrieve the data. So, the data is pulled out from the 2nd bucket and it would not change evenif you run the query any no of times.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: What does 's' at the end of the query mean?

Comment: @ John Deer, that's table alias.